# Using git hooks in Github entreprise to pre-format commit messages

Tags: git, github, jira

Currently, we got Github entreprise integrated with Jira, I want to allow only pull requests to resolve the Jira issue, or require a Git message for commit for example :

```
#ISSUE-123 #time 2d #in-progress
```

Is it possible with Github entreprise ?

I can only see web hooks, they allow you to do action after an event is executed and URL trigged.